# Integer that counts up and is divided by 60

Tags: php, javascript, sql, timestamp

I'm trying to make an ago time, such as, right when the user hits the submit button it starts counting up, now I have a timestamp field in my table but how do I make it so that. Well, here is what I have in mind. When the user presses submit it generates an integer starting at 0 and it counts up each second, and divides by 60, so by the time their is say, 120 of that integer, it will have already been divided by 60 and displayed as 2, or, 2 minutes ago, now, I have no idea on how to do this as I am still a a huge mysql/php noob, so if anyone could explain like I'm 5, that would be amazing, thanks all

A javascript solution would be also good.

Here is my code:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['cname'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['level'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['region'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['time'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['comment'];
echo "</td></tr>";
```

}

That's for the main display page of the table.

Here is the add to table page:

```
 include('config.php');
$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO cw_LFG(cname, level, region, time, comment) VALUES ('".$_POST['cname'] ."','".$_POST['level'] ."','".$_POST['region'] ."','".$_POST['time'] ."','".$_POST ['comment']."')");



header ("Location: lfg.php");
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Are you trying to have it actually show the time increment in realtime?  Or are you just trying to calculate the time when people refresh the web browser?  (Assuming you're doing a web app at all!)

Comment: IMHO you need to rewrite your question and clarify what you are actually trying to achieve. Maybe it's me but right now it seems to be completely incomprehensible.

Comment: To count it as it goes up you would need either a VERY long running php script, or to refresh the page every second. Unless there is a specific reason to do this it would be easier to just store the original timestamp and then compare it to the one on any page refresh. Calculating the value you need from the comparison

Comment: I want the increment to be hidden as part of the <td> but I want the other <td> to refer to it as sort of a guideline for time if that makes sense. So by the time the integer counting up hits 120 it will be divided by 60 and the other <td> will use what it gets and append "minutes ago" to it

Comment: @Kickstart I'm very confused on how to do this, as with my current timestamp field, it has 00:00:00 displaying as the time instead of the actual time of submission for some odd reason. I guess I'm having trouble with actually making it display when the user hits submit. But the main goal I'm trying to achieve is a "minutes ago" type deal, but I have no clue on how to do this :c

Comment: I am very confused about what you want. Php is designed to run pseudo conversationally. Something sends a request, the script runs, returns the data and then ends. Later on another request it done, which could be half a second later or 6 months later. If you want a page that updates every second, adding an extra line to a table then this is possible using AJAX, with a timer to trigger a background call the php script every second, but this is not trivial work.

Comment: I seem to be confusing myself now, here is what I am trying to do: http://gw2lfg.com if you see the elapsed time area it tells how long ago that row was insterted, so for instance if it was submitted 2 minutes ago it would display that. But I looked at the code and noticed a hidden <td> tag that counts up by 1 and divides by 60 to get the elapsed time (maybe this is java? I've been trying to figure out how to do this for 8 hours now)

Comment: As Kickstart pointed out this shouldnt be entirely made in php, as even if somehow would be possible, it would be the misusage of php and also not enviroment friendly at all. Use javascript timer instead, and store the timestamp only on server side.

Comment: If you accept a javascript solution and need help in it, please modify your question, so I will answer it.

Comment: Modified, please explain like I'm 5 on how I could go about doing this with a javascript solution, thanks

Comment: Changed again @derylius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function you can use to create the elapsed time string:

```
function timeElapsed($time) {
    $elapsedTime = time() - $time;

    if ($elapsedTime < 1) {
        return 'Right now';
    }

    // Length of time units
    $units = array( 
        12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60  => 'year',
        30 * 24 * 60 * 60       => 'month',
        24 * 60 * 60            => 'day',
        60 * 60                 => 'hour',
        60                      => 'minute',
        1                       => 'second'
    );

    $string = '';

    foreach ($units as $secs => $unit) {
        $amount = floor($elapsedTime / $secs);

        if ($amount >= 1) {
            $elapsedTime -= $amount * $secs;
            $string .= "$amount $unit" . ($amount > 1 ? 's' : '') . ' ';
        }
    }

    return $string . 'ago';
}
```

When you create a record you save the current time (Here I'm using UNIX timestamp).  When you want to show it to the user you just pass the timestamp to the function and it will return a string like "5 days 2 minutes 30 seconds ago"

**Example Usage**

```
echo timeElapsed(1345678910);
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem I am having now is actually saving the current time when the user presses submit, because it just shows  0000-00-00 00:00:00 as the current time

Comment: Instead of doing $_POST['time'] do date('Y-m-d H:i:s') that will set it at the current time

Comment: why don't you set your table time field to default to the time stamp...then you can update it later when your process is done? and this function above will serve you as "read function" to just display the difference between your time stamp and the current time + "ago"

Comment: Alright that seemed to fix the 0000 problem and it now shows the date, when you say pass the timestamp to the function, how would I go about doing that :p Sorry for all my noob questions

Comment: Yeah I set the type as timestamp and the default to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, but it looks like the Date thing I did up their works, now I have to figure out how to get it to work with the function @chrislondon provided, maybe I'm just being stupid :/

Comment: I seem to have got part of the passing down @chrislondon, but it is referring back to the 1969 date instead of the timestamp I gave it

Comment: @PootisMann oh good :) sorry i was away at lunch or I might've been able to help. Did you use `strtotime()` to convert the "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" time to a unix timestamp

Comment: Yeah i did :P it seems I can no longer ask questions on this account though :/ Can you help with one other thing? I want a row to automatically delete after X minutes

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you are 5 you shouldn't play with JavaScript. Apart from the joke, what you need is when the user hit the submit, you store the timestamp on the server side, since you mentioned in a n SQL table maybe, and on pageload you pass this values to your page (you can send it as a javascript array inside the HTML generated by the PHP, but I would rather go with asking all the data from the server separately using AJAX right after pageload to avoid fuzzy codes) and then just calcualting the difference between those timestamps and the current time and refreshing the cells with those values every second (or minute) using `setInterval()`.

```
var exampleArray = [
  ['user1', timestamp],
  ['user1', timestamp]
];
function count(){
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

  for(var i in exampleArray){   
      DOM.tableToAppendTo.rowToAppendTo.innerHTML += 
    '<td>' + exampleArray[i][0] + '</td>' + 
    '<td>' + calculateTime(exampleArray[i][1] - currentTime) + '</td>'
  }
}
function calculateTime(difference){
  if(difference < 59000){
    return (difference / 60000) + ' minutes ago';
  }else{
    return (difference / 1000) + ' seconds ago';
  }
}
setInterval(count,1000);
```

Comment: Edited my question with my code because I am lost on where to add these things

Comment: please also post the HTML of the table that surrounding the rows